# c++: template helper functions

Tags: c++, templates

I have some functions that don't belong to any class. So right now, they're defined in my program.cpp. Specifically, a simple

```
std::string to_string(double const & value){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << value;
    return ss.str();
}
```

I can use them in my classes when I declare `std::string to_string(double const &);`. But I can't get that to work with templates, i.e. with

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(T const & value){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << value;
    return ss.str();
}
```

In whatever way I declare it, I always end up with "undefined reference to" errors. Any way to do that? The way c++ forces bookkeeping on you makes me sad :(

Comment: Have you included `sstream` ?

Comment: Template definitions need to be included in the source that wants to use it, or explicitly instantiated.

Comment: It helps if you post this error. It also helps if people don't vote the question as duplicate when you are not asking about why templates can only be implemented in the header.

Comment: sstream is not the issue; how would I "explicitly instantiate" such a thing? Simply putting a `std::string to_string(double const &);` doesn't work. The error messages are really just like `...xxx.cpp:(.text+0xc58): undefined reference to `to_string(double const&)'` for every time I use it.

Comment: Now it's a duplicate for sure. The function def (including body) needs to go into a .h file, include that .h file